# An Integral and its limit

Tags: integration, limits, probability-distributions

Consider the following integral,

$$K(\alpha)=\int_\mathbb{R}\log^2(g/f)(g/f)^\alpha f \, \mathrm{d}\mu$$
where $\alpha\geq 0$, $\,\mu$ is some measure and $f,g$ are some *distinct* continuous probability density functions on reals.

Prove either of the two:

> **Claim 1**: $\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}K(\alpha)=\infty$
>
> **Claim 2**: $K(\alpha)$ takes its minimum value on $\alpha\in[0,1]$.

I think

$\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow\infty}K(\alpha)\neq 0$ can prove both claims.

Comment: If $g=f$, with $f>0$, then the integral is 0. As well, there's no mention of how to define this integral outside the support of $f,g$.

Comment: @AlexR. I forgot to mention that they were distinct density functions. The support is reals and integral is also on the reals. Do I miss some point?